# wrong currency convert when calling "payment_mobile_pricepoints" to facebook graph

Tags: python, facebook

Im using python graph class to call to "payment_mobile_pricepoints". im setting 1 coin to be 0.10 using:

```
meta property="product:price:amount" content="0.10"
meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD"
```

and calling the graph api using:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(tycoon.access_token)
params = {}
params["fields"] = "payment_mobile_pricepoints"
msg = graph.get_connections("me", "", **params)
```

the convertion should be between USD to NIS (new israel shekel).
im getting:

```
payer_amount: 2
payout_base_amount: 0.59
```

so according the api one coin should be 0.29 instead of ~0.35 (which is the actual rate).

I tried also with GBP with again wrong convertion.

when im trying to actually buy the amount in the facebook payments popup is correct (so it is just the api call i guess).

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/paymentflow/#pricejumping

solved my problem.